# Java Error when using the line usbList.add(roots[i]);

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("USB Configuration");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

}



}
```

Here is my controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{
public ComboBox usbListComboBox;
public ObservableList usbList;
public File[] roots = File.listRoots();
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        for (int i = 0; i< roots.length; i++){
           usbList.add(roots[i]);
        }
        usbListComboBox.setItems(usbList);
}
}
```

Here is my fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<GridPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<children>
  <ComboBox fx:id = "usbListComboBox" promptText="Configuration">
     <items>

     </items>
  </ComboBox>
</children>

</GridPane>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/JohnsonL/Desktop/flashTranserProj/flashTransferProj/out/production/flashTransferProj/sample/sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:18)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

The error I am getting is coming from the line:

```
usbList.add(roots[i]);
```

When I remove this line It runs fine. I have seen other posts with similar errors and have had this error in the past but nothing that I have seen has worked. I am unsure if I am doing something wrong when I am trying the solutions so they might solve my issue and I am doing something wrong.

Comment: usbList is null, because you haven't initialized it, so calling a method on it causes a NullPointerException.

Comment: That worked thanks